# How to set QMainWindow title

Tags: c++, qt, qmainwindow

How do I set the title of a QMainWindow?

I tried googling and found setCaption(), but it appears it no longer works in Qt 4.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The method is `setWindowTitle()`:

```
setWindowTitle(const QString &)
```

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#windowTitle-prop

Comment: setCaption is supposed to do the same thing, though its deprecated now which I guess due to bad API naming.

Comment: Well, I was trying setTitle(), and when it didn't work, tried searching the Public Functions of QMainWindow in the Qt Assistant for title and it didn't find this. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: The confusion could come from the fact that `setWindowTitle` is a method of `QWidget`, not `QMainWindow`, even though the concept of “window title” is not even applicable to most widgets.

Comment: @bdesham, actually you can make a window out of any widget if you just tell it to exec(). If you actually really want to do that is another thing.