# How to set Windows taskbar title of a QMainWindow?

Tags: c++, qt

Out of curiosity: I am currently developing a Qt application on Windows 7. I want to set the window title to display in the taskbar. `setWindowTitle` is not applicable as my UI is a `QMainWindow`, not a `QWidget`.

I have a `QString` with the title, but I can't set it. I set the `QMainWindow` title in the Qt Designer but that's static. All I had reached is this:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
: QMainWindow(parent)
{
  // ....
  QApplication::setApplicationDisplayName(qAppTitle);
  parent->setWindowTitle(qAppTitle);
  // ...
}
```

This turns the window title in my taskbar into:

> [title from Qt Designer] - [qAppTitle variable]

Sucks.

Ideas?

Comment: What makes you think setWindowTitle isn't applicable?  Or, more to the point, that a QMainWindow is not a QWidget?

Comment: Because 1) QMainWindow is not a QWidget and 2) setWindowTitle has no visible effect.

Comment: It's possible with `setWindowTitle`, How do you use it?please update your code, put your code.

Comment: edited initial posting. :-)

Comment: This works.. unless you mean its because W7 has icons by default?

Comment: No it doesn't, it crashes immediately unless I comment the `parent->` line - and then the window title reads "[title from Qt Designer] - [qAppTitle variable]" :/

Comment: Ah, gotcha! Remove the call to parent, just call the setWindowTitle that is a member of QMainWindow

Comment: Great, now it reads "[qAppTitle] - [qAppTitle]"... we're getting closer!

Comment: Thats it - done. You only see the first part because its being executed from the designer :)

Comment: No, I get the same result when directly executing the .exe file.

Comment: Fixed: I had to comment the `setApplicationDisplayName` line too. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QMainWindow has a setWindowTitle the same as QWidget (because it is one), see this question:

[How to set QMainWindow title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549859/how-to-set-qmainwindow-title)

Thus the solution is:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
: QMainWindow(parent)
{
  setWindowTitle("Hello world");
}
```

http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/qwidget.html#windowTitle-prop

Also

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qmainwindow.html

```
"QMainWindow Class

The QMainWindow class provides a main application window. More...
#include <QMainWindow>
Inherits: QWidget."
```

[image]

Comment: (After changes, see previous discussion:) Thanks! Solved.

Comment: setApplicationDisplayName seems to be the only way on my system to change the window decoration's title. setWindowTitle had me running down a dead end for hours.